# Am I eligible for the Taiwan Travel Authorization Certificate with a H1B US Visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, taiwan, h1b-visas, taipei

I am an Indian citizen, currently working in the US on the H1B visa.

I was under the impression that Indians with a valid US visa can simply apply for a Travel Authorization Certificate online. However, I recently read that the US visa cannot be a "work permit" so I don't know if the H1B counts.

Am I eligible to apply for the Travel Authorization Certificate?

I plan to travel in 1.5 weeks, so not sure what my options are!

Answer (score 2):

You can see the actual official requirements at the [official Taiwan web site where you would apply for the certificate](https://niaspeedy.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast/):

> ### Online application for ROC Travel Authorization Certificate for nationals of Cambodia, India, Indonesia, Laos, Myanmar, and Vietnam
>
> Nationals of Cambodia, India, Indonesia, Laos, Myanmar, and Vietnam
> can apply online for an ROC Travel Authorization Certificate
>
> Nationals of these countries intending to submit an online application
> for such a certificate should carefully read the following before
> proceeding to the next page.
>
> #### *Basic requirements*
>
> To be eligible for an ROC Travel Authorization
> Certificate, the following three basic requirements must be met:
>
> 1. The applicant’s passport must have remaining validity of at least six months starting from the date of arrival in Taiwan.
> 2. The applicant must possess an onward/return air or ferry ticket.
> 3. The applicant has never been employed as a blue-collar worker in Taiwan.
>
> #### *Additional requirements*
>
> In addition to the aforementioned basic
> requirements, one of the following requirements must also be met:
>
> 1. The applicant possesses at least one of the following documents issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, Korea, New Zealand, any of EU and
>    Schengen countries, the United Kingdom, or the United States:
>
>    - Valid resident or permanent resident card
>    - Valid entry visa (may be electronic visa)
>    - Resident card or visa that has expired less than 10 years prior to the date of arrival in Taiwan
>
>    ※Applicants who use an electronic visa issued by Australia or New Zealand as the required document must present the valid Australia or
>    New Zealand electronic visa as entering Taiwan.
>
>    ※Applicants who use a visa issued by Japan as the required document must present the proof record of entering Japan or a
>    confirmed onward ticket to Japan when entering Taiwan.
> 2. The applicant possesses an entry visa or resident card issued by the ROC at any point in the past 10 years and has no record of
>    immigration irregularities or law violations in Taiwan. However,
>    holders of ROC entry visas bearing the remark FL (migrant worker), X
>    (others), or P with “Special permission from MOFA” (visa and eVisa for
>    “Project for Simplifying Visa Regulations for High-end Group Tourists
>    from Southeast Asian Countries (Project Kuan-Hong)” ever issued), as
>    well as holders of ROC resident cards with stated purpose of residence
>    being migrant worker (移工), are not eligible for an ROC Travel
>    Authorization Certificate.
>
> #### *Notes*
>
> 1. An approved ROC Travel Authorization Certificate is valid for 90 days. Multiple entries within these 90 days are allowed. The holder of
>    an ROC Travel Authorization Certificate may stay in Taiwan for 14
>    days, starting from the day after arrival. If the holder wishes to
>    apply for another ROC Travel Authorization Certificate, he or she must
>    do so seven days prior to the expiry of the current certificate.
> 2. If any mistake is made during the online application process, the applicant may submit a new application.
> 3. Online applications can only be made by persons holding valid regular passports. Persons holding temporary, emergency, or informal
>    passports, or travel documents other than a passport, cannot submit
>    online applications.
> 4. The visas in the aforementioned list of required documents do not include work permits.
> 5. Holders of aforementioned visas bearing such stamps as VOID, CANCELLED, or CANCELLED WITHOUT PREJUDICE are not eligible for an ROC
>    Travel Authorization Certificate.
> 6. With regard to resident cards or visas that have expired less than 10 years ago, this means that the time between the expiry date of the
>    resident card or visa and the date of arrival in Taiwan may not be
>    longer than 10 years. If no expiry date or validity period is given on
>    the resident card or visa, the 10-year period refers to the time
>    between the resident card or visa’s issuing date and the date of
>    arrival in Taiwan.
> 7. Applicants who hold permanent resident cards with no expiry date may enter 9999 for year, 12 for month and 31 for day in the Date
>    field.
> 8. Once the application has been approved, the applicant should print out the ROC Travel Authorization Certificate. The applicant must
>    present the certificate and the required documents for inspection when
>    entering Taiwan. Entry will be denied if the required documents are
>    not produced.
> 9. Nationals of Indonesia who possess a valid Japan Visa Waiver Registration are eligible for an ROC Travel Authorization Certificate.
> 10. Please fill in an (online) Arrival Card for immigration inspection each time before reentry within the validity of this certificate.
>     https://acard.immigration.gov.tw/nia_acard

Comment: Point #4 under Notes says: "The visas in the aforementioned list of required documents do not include work permits." :(

Comment: You're right, it does say that. The question is, whether the US visa is a work permit. My understanding is that the EAD card is your work permit. But some countries do have combined visas/work permits.